# RouteReuseStrategy not working for routing with dynamic params

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular15

**router-strategy.ts**

```
import {RouteReuseStrategy,ActivatedRouteSnapshot,DetachedRouteHandle,} from '@angular/router';

export class RtgRouteReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
  private routeLeftFrom: string | undefined;
  private handlers: { [key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle } = {};

  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    this.routeLeftFrom = route.routeConfig!.path;
    return route.data['shouldReuseRoute'] || false;
  }

  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handler: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
    if (handler) {
      this.handlers[this.getUrl(route)] = handler;
    }
  }

  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    const url = this.getUrl(route);
    return !!this.handlers[url];
  }

  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle | null {
    if (!route.routeConfig || route.routeConfig.loadChildren) {
      return null;
    }

    return this.handlers[this.getUrl(route)];
  }

  shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,current: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    const reUseUrl = future.routeConfig?.data?.['reuse'];
    const defaultReuse = future.routeConfig === current.routeConfig;
    return reUseUrl || defaultReuse;
  }

  getUrl(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): string {
    const url = route.url.map((segment) => segment.path).join('/');
    return url;
  }
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './core/authguard/auth.guard';
import { RtgCreationComponent } from './modules/rtg-form/components/rtg-creation/rtg-creation.component';
import { RtgViewComponent } from './modules/rtg-form/components/rtg-view/rtg-view.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: "rtgmaster", pathMatch: "full" },
  {
    path: "rtgmaster",
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: AppComponent
  },
  {
    path:"form/:rtgId/:email/:phnNumber",
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component:RtgCreationComponent,
     data: {
        shouldReuseRoute: true,
        reuseRoutesFrom: ["rtgmaster","form/:rtgId/:email/:phnNumber/view"]
     }
  },
  {
    path: "form/:rtgId/:email/:phnNumber/view",
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component:RtgViewComponent
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I can create multiple instances of **RtgViewComponent** & single instance of **RtgCreationComponent**. I am just opening these components inside a stepper(i,e like browser tabs) by looping & each component instance will be created with dynamic query params for both **RtgViewComponent** & **RtgCreationComponent**.

I need to restore form data in **RtgCreationComponent** after routing from **RtgViewComponent  & AppComponent**.

**Issue I am facing is:**

If I create **RtgCreationComponent** first then creates multiple number of **RtgViewComponent**. Then routing back to
**RtgCreationComponent**  from **RtgViewComponent/AppComponent** works fine(i,e form data/router instance wont't be destroyed).

**but**

If I create **RtgViewComponent** first, then creates   **RtgCreationComponent**.Then routing back to
**RtgCreationComponent**  from **RtgViewComponent** breaks the router instacne but routing back from **AppComponent** work fine.

Please suggest what wrong with my **router-strategy.ts** code

Was able to reproduce in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-reactive-forms-validation-ppv7il?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpage-demo%2Fpage-demo.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fpage-demo%2Fpage-demo.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Frouter-strategy.ts), Attaching FYR.

Comment: maybe you can try this: https://hastebin.com/share/mumaqofasa.typescript it is used to generate a unique str that represents the *route's path*, which can be used as a key for storing and retrieving `DetachedRouteHandle` objects. or alternatively maybe you can say temporary form data in a service and then check and if  you have it reuse it? or as another way maybe try to use somhow ActivatedRoute and paramMap and queryParams to get dynamic state based on your URL params. and i you create and destroy the object consider using ngOnInit (to load/restore data)and ngOnDestroy(to save form state)

Answer (score 1):

Custom RouteReuseStrategy is a bad idea nearly in 100% cases. It is much more complicated than it may seem, it is error prone and API documentation is also very bad on this topic.

RouteReuseStrategy can only cache component tree, you can not cache individual components.

I don't completely understand your case but I think it is not possible to make strategy better than default one. Just cache data instead of caching component instances.

Comment: I cant cache the data. There are 3 forms & the form fields are dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

First:

`path: "form/:rtgId/:email/:phnNumber/view",`

Should be **before**

`path:"form/:rtgId/:email/:phnNumber",`

Second: you should subscribe to ActivateRouter.Params

```
constructor(private activateRouter:ActivateRouter){}
ngOnInit(){
   this.activateRouter.Params.subscribe(res=>{
       ...
   }
}
```